# Selecting all checkboxes that don't have a particular Class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to select all the checkboxes except those that have a particular class?

```
$(':checkbox')
```

This selects all checkboxes but I have some I don't want to get in the selection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not) method, or the [`:not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector):

```
$(':checkbox').not('.noSelect');
$(':checkbox:not(.noSelect)');
```

Where `noSelect` is the class you want excluded.

NB for optimal speed (enhancing for `querySelectorAll`), you code should probably look like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:not(.noSelect)');
```

Comment: +1 for the optimization. Maybe he also wants `:not([class])`, depending on what *"except those who have a css class"* really means.

Comment: @Felix A good point, but I think it would be better in any case to exclude a *particular* class. Much more predictable behaviour if you later add a class to a checkbox that doesn't currently have one.

Comment: Thanks works like a charm.. Tx for optimization too.. I accept as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do the exact opposite.  Give the ones that you want to select their own class.  And then select those.  Something like:

```
$(':checkbox.myclass')
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will do

```
$(':checkbox:not(.myclass)')
```

like

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="myclass"/>
<input type="button" value="ss" onclick="alert( $(':checkbox:not(.myclass)').length);"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':checkbox[class!=except-class]')
```

Comment: Attribute values have to be in quotes and this will not work if the element has several classes.